# Handle multiple tokenURI in one NFT smart contract to different mint functions

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, nft, contract-debugging

I have a simple nft contract and I want to create mint functions that if you press one or another that tokenId is bound to a URI I decide.

I already tried multiple ways to do it but I got an error that doesn't let me complete it.

The error is that when I mint in one or another mint function the URI is not the one I decided. So something is happening when the token is created but I don’t see the error.

Let's put a sample of the code

````
pragma solidity >=0.8.9 <0.9.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol";

contract Testing is ERC721, Ownable, ReentrancyGuard {

  using Counters for Counters.Counter;
  using Strings for uint256;

  mapping(address => bool) public whitelistedAddresses;

  string public uriPrefix;
  string public uriSuffix = '.json';


  Counters.Counter private _tokenIdCounter;

  enum TokenType { Type1, Type2 }

  mapping (uint256 => TokenType) tokenType;

  string tokenURI1 = 'ipfs://test1';
  string tokenURI2 = 'ipfs://test2';
 
  uint256 public maxSupply = 1000;
  uint256 public maxWhitelistSupply = 200;
  uint256 public maxPresaleSupply = 400;
  uint256 public maxMintAmountPerTx = 400;

  bool public paused = false;
  bool public revealed = false;


  address public a1;
  address public a2;


  constructor(
    string memory _tokenName,
    string memory _tokenSymbol,
    string memory _uriPrefix
  ) ERC721(_tokenName, _tokenSymbol) {
    setUriPrefix(_uriPrefix);
  }



    function mint1(uint256 _mintAmount) public payable { 
      uint256 _tokenId = _tokenIdCounter.current(); 
      tokenType[_tokenId] = TokenType.Type1;
      _tokenIdCounter.increment();
      _safeMint(_msgSender(), _mintAmount);   
    }
    
    function mint2(uint256 _mintAmount) public payable { 
      uint256 _tokenId = _tokenIdCounter.current();
      tokenType[_tokenId] = TokenType.Type2;
      _tokenIdCounter.increment();
      _safeMint(_msgSender(), _mintAmount); 
    }



  function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId) public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
      if (tokenType[tokenId] == TokenType.Type1) {
          return string(abi.encodePacked(tokenURI1, tokenId.toString()));
      } else {
          return string(abi.encodePacked(tokenURI2, tokenId.toString()));
      }
  }

 /* function tokenURI(uint256 _tokenId) public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
    require(_exists(_tokenId), 'ERC721Metadata: URI query for nonexistent token');

    string memory currentBaseURI = _baseURI();
    return bytes(currentBaseURI).length > 0
        ? string(abi.encodePacked(currentBaseURI, _tokenId.toString(), uriSuffix))
        : '';
  } */

  function setMaxMintAmountPerTx(uint256 _maxMintAmountPerTx) public onlyOwner {
    maxMintAmountPerTx = _maxMintAmountPerTx;
  }


  function setUriPrefix(string memory _uriPrefix) public onlyOwner {
    uriPrefix = _uriPrefix;
  }

  function setUriSuffix(string memory _uriSuffix) public onlyOwner {
    uriSuffix = _uriSuffix;
  }

  function setPaused(bool _state) public onlyOwner {
    paused = _state;
  }


        // Set team addresses
    function setAddresses(address[] memory _a) public onlyOwner {
        a1 = _a[0];
        a2 = _a[1];
    }

  function withdraw() public onlyOwner {
    // This will pay another address 97% of the NFT sale.
    // =============================================================================
    (bool tw, ) = payable(a1).call{value: address(this).balance * 97 / 100}("");
    require(tw);
    // =============================================================================
    // This will transfer the remaining contract balance to the owner.
    // Do not remove this otherwise you will not be able to withdraw the funds.
    // =============================================================================
    (bool va, ) = payable(a2).call{value: address(this).balance}("");
    require(va);
    // =============================================================================
  }

  function _baseURI() internal view virtual override returns (string memory) {
    return uriPrefix;
  }
}``` 

The error is that I mint, let’s say, 2 tokens in mint1 function and 2 more in mint2 function, so when I check the URI of those tokens, the tokens number 1,3 and 4 have the tokenURI1 and just the 2nd token has the tokenURI2. This is an example of course but that is the error that is happening.
````

Comment: Semi-related, but I think you are misusing Openzeppelin contracts. `_safeMint` takes a `tokenId` as second argument, not an amount of tokens. Are you sure you're using it correctly?

Comment: I was using firstly ERC721A type of contract but i modified just because i didn´t think it will work that way, but in any way i´m having the error.

Comment: @Pablo The code works fine for me. How are you executing mint1, & mint2 functions? Both of these function take the tokenID (the index) as argument, and assign the TokenType to the token at that index.
So, if you execute the mint1 function first with the argument 0, and then 1, and then subsequently execute mint2 twice with arguments 2 and 3, then the tokenURL for tokenID 0 will be ipfs://test10. For tokenID 1, tokenURL will be ipfs://test01. Similarly, tokenURL for tokenIDs 2 and 3 will be the tokenURL for tokenID 0 will be ipfs://test22 and ipfs://test22 respectively. This is as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Shariq. Thats the error i´m getting. i am executing the code exactly like that. First i mint 1 nft in the mint1 function, and then mint another one in the mint2 function, but if i mint first in the mint2 function, for example, 2 nfts, and then mint 3 in the mint1 functions, the TokenURL are not the expected. mostly of the tokens get the TokenURL of the TokenURI1 and not the expected.